# Do outbound TCP connections prevent port binding for listening?

Tags: ubuntu, port, tcp

I'm running an application that is trying to listen on port `34002`.  When it tries to do so, it gets the error:

```
Address already in use
```

When I use `lsof` to find the culprit, I find that it's an outbound TCP connection:

```
sudo lsof -i | grep "some-process"
some-command 53344  some-process    7u  IPv4 344298      0t0  TCP <my-local-ip-redacted>:34002-><remote-ip-redacted>:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

This seems odd to me.  Outbound TCP sessions are started on randomly selected ports.  **Does the OS really prevent binding to that port it randomly selected?**  Or am I interpreting this incorrectly?  It seems like there would be some logic for moving the session to a different port.  I can't imagine this would be an uncommon occurrence.

Comment: What does `ss -tnlp` or `netstat -tnlp` have to say ?

Comment: Unfortunately the machine is no longer in the same state as when I wrote the question. But the process that had an outbound session doesn't show usage of any ports that show up when running those commands

Comment: When a process sends traffic to the network it originates from some IP and some port. When traffic comes back, if it is "labeled" with the exact same port, the OS knows that it has to deliver that traffic to that specific process that started it. If, at the same time, another process can bind to same part and listen for any incoming traffic, when some come, how the OS could find out if it has to hand it to the originating first process or to the process listening on the port? It can't, hence the restriction.

Comment: "In theory", applications binding to ports are started early at boot and hence get the ports without difficulty, and then all later processes that need ephemeral ports are handled by the OS in order not to use ports already in use by listening applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the OS really prevent binding to that port it randomly selected?

If a port is in use then it is in use. It does not matter if it was randomly allocated or explicitly selected, all what matters is that it is in use. It is advised that you don't bind services to ports in the ephemeral port range, because then exactly this can happen.

Comment: Ah, so the behavior is limited to a specific port range. Wasn't aware I was trying to bind to an ill-advised port.

Comment: RFC6335 defines: "the Dynamic Ports, also known as the Private or Ephemeral Ports, from 49152-65535 (never assigned)", which hence is not the case of 34002. Except that not all OS follow this definition... on linux it is configurable but by default the range 32768-61000